# Hide individual select menu options if they match the condition in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have 3 select drop-down menus. I would like to be able to hide individual options in the drop-down menus depending on the selections in the other 2 menus. For example:

If I select the subject 'English' in drop-down one. I would like 'English' and 'English & creative writing' hidden in the 2 other menus.

All I have managed to do so far is add a class to the whole menu and not the individual entry. My code is in this fiddle:

Can anyone help please?

The JS file data

```
export default [
  "Education",
  "Economics",
  "English",
  "English & Creative Writing",
  "French",
  "History",  
  "Law",
  "Marketing",
  "Mathematics",  
  "Psychology", 
  "Spanish",
];
```

The Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="bs">
    <div id="formarea">
      <form id="form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="cascading-dropdown">
            <div class="form-group dropdown">
              <label for="Subject one">Subject one</label>

              <select
                id="selectmenuone"
                v-model="selectedSubjectone"
                class="form-control"
                accesskey="a"
              >
                <option value="">Select subject one</option>

                <option
                  :class="hidesubject"
                  v-for="subjectone in Hdata"
                  :value="subjectone.text"
                  :key="subjectone"
                  >{{ subjectone }}</option
                >
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group dropdown">
              <label for="Subject two">Subject two</label>
              <select
                id="selectmenutwo"
                :disabled="subjecttwo.length == 0"
                v-model="selectedSubjecttwo"
                class="form-control"
                accesskey="b"
              >
                <option value="">Select a second subject</option>
                <option
                  :class="hidesubject"
                  v-for="subjectsecond in subjecttwo"
                  :key="subjectsecond"
                  >{{ subjectsecond }}</option
                >
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group dropdown">
              <label for="Subject three">Subject three</label>

              <select
                id="selectmenuthree"
                :disabled="subjectsthree.length == 0"
                v-model="selectedSubjectthree"
                class="form-control"
                accesskey="c"
              >
                <option value="selected">Select a third subject</option>
                <option
                  :class="hidesubject"
                  v-for="subjectthird in subjectsthree"
                  :key="subjectthird"
                  :value="subjectthird"
                  >{{ subjectthird }}</option
                >
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <ul class="yousearchedfor pl-1">
            <li v-if="selectedSubjectone">
              1st choice: <strong>{{ selectedSubjectone }}</strong>
            </li>
            <li v-if="selectedSubjecttwo">
              2nd choice:
              <strong> {{ selectedSubjecttwo }}</strong>
            </li>
            <li v-if="selectedSubjectthree">
              3rd choice:
              <strong> {{ selectedSubjectthree }}</strong>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p v-if="selectedSubjectthree">
            This is your choice
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// let hass = require("../assets/subjects");
import hsubjects from "../assets/subjects";

export default {
  name: "SubjectsCombinations",

  props: {
    msg: String,
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      subjects,
      subjecttwo: [],
      subjectsthree: [],
      selectedSubjectone: "",
      selectedSubjecttwo: "",
      selectedSubjectthree: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    Hdata() {
      return subjects;
    },
    hidesubject() {
      return [
        "hide",
        {
          hideclosed: this.selectedSubjectone.key === "English",
        },
        {
          showclosed: this.selectedSubjecttwo.key != "English",
        },
      ];
    },
  },

  // Console.log(this.selectedSubjectone.text === "English" ? "hideclosed" : "showclosed”)

   

  watch: {
    selectedSubjectone: function() {
      // Clear previously selected values
      this.subjecttwo = [];
      this.subjectsthree = [];
      this.selectedSubjecttwo = "";
      this.selectedSubjectthree = "";
      // Populate list of subjects in the second dropdown
      if (this.selectedSubjectone.length > 0) {
        this.subjecttwo = this.hasssubjects;
      }
    },
    selectedSubjecttwo: function() {
      // Clear previously selected values
      this.subjectsthree = [];

      // We have a subject one and two. Populate list of subjects in the third dropdown
      if (this.selectedSubjecttwo.length > 0) {
        this.subjectsthree = this.hasssubjects;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.yousearchedfor li + li:not(:last-child):before {
  content: ", ";
}
ul.yousearchedfor li + li:last-child:before {
  content: "\00a0 & ";
}
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child:after {
  content: ".";
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove certain items from the select drop-down menu using VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571209/remove-certain-items-from-the-select-drop-down-menu-using-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very complicated. [Try something like this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

```js
<template>
  <select v-model="one">
    <option v-for="subject in subjects">
      {{ subject }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="two" :disabled="!one">
    <option v-for="subject in subjects.filter(item => item.split(' ')[0].indexOf(this.one.split(' ')[0]))">
      {{ subject }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="three" :disabled="!two">
    <option v-for="subject in subjects.filter(item => item.split(' ')[0].indexOf(this.one.split(' ')[0]) && item.split(' ')[0].indexOf(this.two.split(' ')[0]))">
      {{ subject }}
    </option>
  </select>
  
  <div>
    Selected: {{one}} {{two}} {{three}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      subjects: [
        "Education",
        "Economics",
        "English",
        "English & Creative Writing",
        "French",
        "History",  
        "Law",
        "Marketing",
        "Mathematics",  
        "Psychology", 
        "Spanish"
      ],
      one: "",
      two: "",
      three: "",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Thank you!